# What is difference between command prompt started via start menu or directly from explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, ssh, shell

In windows, we can start command line via start menu [start menu >> All Programs >> Accessories >> 'Command Prompt' or just type in cmd.exe start edit box for that matter]

The 2nd way is directly from file explorer. Hold shift key down, right click in a folder and select 'Open command window here'.

Why are these two different sometimes? I mean the paths are different and for that reason sometime things work in one command prompt but will not work in the other!

For example I just installed doxygen. If I invoke command prompt via start menu, it is recognized and the doxygen command works. If I invoke it through file explorer, this command is not recognized.

I am sure this has bitten me before as well when my ssh session will work in one command prompt but not the other!

Why is there a difference and what actually is this difference? Can we make both use the same environment?

Comment: Have you changed the path since installing `doxygen`? Any new `cmd` shell should pick up the new environment. You may have to restart `explorer` to also pick up the new environment. Run `set` in both cases to see if there is a difference.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think this might be the correct answer. After I killed all instances of explorer and restarted it, it did recognize the command. If you put this in answer, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: **What things specifically work in one and not the other?**  Update your question do not post a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound do you expect me to spend a week and figure out what works and what not? It can be literally unlimited things to test :) I have already said what doesn't work.

Comment: @zadane It is as I expected. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is there a difference and what actually is this difference?

If you have changed the environment (for example changing the `Path` after  installing `doxygen`) then any new instance of a `cmd` shell would pick up the new environment.

On the other hand `explorer` will need to be restarted to pick up the new environment (as it inherits the environment passed to it when it was started).

If you run `set` in the two different command shells (one started from the start menu, and the other from "Open command window here") then you will see the difference (before and after the changes) in the two environments).

I expect you will find that `doxygen` is in the `Path` for one and not for the other.

Comment: I tried this on my home PC now and strangely enough I didn't have to restart explorer and doxygen worked in both command prompts right after I installed doxygen. Maybe I have full privileges on home PC? Maybe there are corporate rules setup on work machine? Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the start menu is a shortcut in which you can e.g. define admin privileges. When you go via the .exe, you have to right click and "run as admin".

Comment: It doesn't do anything with admin privileges.

Comment: @zadane - Your question, asks what the difference between the two actions, this is the difference.

Comment: I meant in the environment, it's obvious the initial starting directories are different.

Comment: Update your question so that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the properties of that shortcut (Start -> Accessories -> Command Prompt) you will see that it has `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` written in "Start in", which is why it starts there instead of `C:\Windows\system32`. Also notice that "Run as administrator" is not selected by default.

That command is not recognized probably because it requires administrator priviliges.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with admin privileges.